# My service not restart when application close

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I create a service started when application is running, but this service is closed when I close application.

I use return `START_STICKY` on `onStartCommand`, but this service not restart.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by... *"when i close application"*?

Comment: You can make your service call again in onDestroy method of service classes.

Comment: Show us some code: service and how you start it

Comment: My service is started when application is open, but when i close all applications with android button to close all, my service is stopped too. My service is started on android reboot too, but if i open application and use close all this service is closed too.